SharePoint Forms (new feature), what can we do and what we can not do
Recently I got the new Forms feature inside our lists:-

And seems it provides a better layout compared to the built-in forms. and more options for customizations. but I am not sure if those forms can totally replace customizing forms using Power Apps, such as :-

Hiding a field based on other field value?
Make a field optional/mandatory based on other field value?
Wrap certain fields under sections? something as follow:-


in other words, does this form provide the same level of customization which we can do using Power Apps?
Thanks

No, it doesn't. You can just do a few cosmetic changes, but in order to buid multiple column layouts and complex business rules, you're still better off with Power Apps.

ok noted, thanks
